Seeking clarification on whether 'head' is an array of type ListNode, or is it just the 'head' node - LeetCode
I am seeking clarification on whether 'head' is the head of a linked list or it is an list of type [ListNode]. 
I think a screenshot of the question will bring more context so let me add it.
The solution boilerplate code suggests that 'head' is an optional list of type 'ListNode'...

But the questions suggest that 'head' is the head of a linked list...

Furthermore, the example test cases suggest that 'head' is a list... 

My candid and maybe dumb question is...which is which? 
Thank you in advance for anyone who will take their time to look at this.
This is my first Linked List question and so I am still trying to wrap my head around the concept.

Please.... don't post images of code. Instead type the code. (Think of accessibility).

The type of the argument is ListNode and it is optional meaning it could be None. The square brackets are not hinting to a list type, but are merely a notation to indicate what is optional. So, no, it is not a list. It is a ListNode.
